# Query regarding app distribution system

Tags: ios, version, distribution

I have an question regarding app distribution system via app store.

I have an app on app store which interacts with a different client-servers at various locations. It functions like version 1.0 of iphone app will be able to properly interact with version 1.0 of the client-server. Now the problem is few of my clients are late/reluctant in upgrading their server to which the iphone users connect. Once I release an update(say 2.0) for my iphone app there are few client-server which are still running 1.0 version. And if the end users of these clients installs the update (2.0) for his iphone app (unknowingly, the client-server which he is gonna connect to is still on 1.0), he makes his app unusable.
how to deal with these types of scenarios?

Can I develop my new updates to the application which interacts with the server before upgrading themselves OR can I develop something which automatically rolls back the update if server version mismatches?

Kindly suggest how to deal with this problem!

Would extremely grateful for your suggestions.

Many thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 0):

You can't do either things that you mentioned. The app store guidelines forbid removing functionality (aka compatibility with 1.0) from the app, however they are fairly lenient about this. Regardless, it's a bad user experience to not support recent older versions of your client/server software.

Most people will place a big warning at the beginning of their "What's new" text, like "WARNING: This version does not work with server app version 1.0." It's somewhat effective if the person bothers to read that, however it's a bit crude.

In any case, version 2 of the app should not simply crash - you should provide feedback via a `UIAlertView` if their server version is not compatible with the client.

Furthermore, your server version 2 should continue to send responses that version 1 can parse, or send back an error message that you display to the user via a `UIAlertView` that tells them that they need to update the app.